# Decode HTTPS request payload on server using jNetPcap

Tags: java, network-programming, pcap, packet-sniffers, jnetpcap

Before jumping into the problem I would like to share that what is the structure of my network. I have 3 computers where 1 is acting as a server and rest of the machines are acting as clients. Server is connected to internet and sharing it with other two machines. 
I have been trying to log all the HTTPS request on my server by using Jnetpcap library. I have logged all the requests from my HTTP very easily. But, unable to get grip on HTTPS requests.

My PacketHandler snippet is :

```
 PcapPacketHandler<String> jpacketHandler = new PcapPacketHandler<String>() {

            public void nextPacket(PcapPacket packet, String user) {

                System.out.printf("Received packet at %s caplen=%-4d len=%-4d %s\n",
                        new Date(packet.getCaptureHeader().timestampInMillis()),
                        packet.getCaptureHeader().caplen(), // Length actually captured  
                        packet.getCaptureHeader().wirelen(), // Original length   
                        user // User supplied object  
                );
            }
        };
```

In response it returns

> youtube.com.https ......Blah Blah

But, didn't return the youtube video ID that I was willing to capture.

Answer (score 1):

It's the "S" in "HTTPS" that's the problem.

HTTP requests and replies are plain text.  HTTPS is HTTP-over-{SSL,TLS}, and the plain text being sent in those requests and replies is almost always encrypted.  You'd have to decrypt it, which is Not Easy - Wireshark has code that can *sometimes* do it, *if* you provide the right information, but, as [the Wireshark Wiki entry for SSL](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL) indicates, and as a look at the Wireshark code to do the decryption will show, there's a significant amount of work involved.

Comment: If I want to capture the SSL traffic passed through my server. Can I not access it? As I am a service provider and would like to know who is accessing what?

Comment: "If I want to capture the SSL traffic passed through my server. Can I not access it ?As I am a service provider and would like to know who is accessing what?"  There's "can" and there's "may".  Yes, if it's your server, people might say you *may* access it, as in "they don't think it's wrong for you to access it", but you *can* do it only if you sniff traffic and can decrypt it *or* if you put logging capability *into your server* (if it doesn't already have it) and use *that* rather than third-party packet sniffing.

Comment: What server software are you running?  Can you configure it to log traffic to and from all clients?

Comment: I want to develop a software I am not using any software.

Comment: "I am not using any software."  No, but the computer acting as a server *is* using software to provide HTTP service.  What software is *it* using?